# iteration on numbers with no 2 same digits

Tags: c++, iterator

I dont know if it is asked (I couldn't find any).

I want to iterate on this kind of numbers implemented on array;

```
int a[10];
int i = 0;
for( ; i < 10; i++ )
    a[i] = i+1;
```

now the array has 

"1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10" 
     and I want to get 
"1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 10 9"
     and then  
        "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9 8 10"
             "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9 10 8"   
 . . . .

I tried to get an algorithm but I couldn't figure it out.
Is there an easy way to implement "next" iterator for this kind of problems?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [`std::next_permutation`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/).